# Trying to copy data from a file to an array but it gives me error

Tags: java, arrays, file

Hi I am new on programing and I am having a problem I am trying to copy some things from a file to a array
and I just want to copy in the position 1,2,3 and 4 from the file. Example copy to the array `11 , G , 0 , 20`.

> FILE TEXT:
> 0;11;G;0;200;1
> 2;10;F;0;300;2
> 0;12;J;0;100;3

```java
String[][] aa = new String[100][6];
try {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(new File("Turmas.txt"));
    x.useDelimiter("[;\n]");

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (x.hasNext()) {
                aa[i][j] = x.next();
            }
        }
    }
    x.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
        null, "An error occurred, try restarting the program!", 
        "ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
    );
}

String[][] aaa = new String[100][4];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        if (aa[i][j] == null) {
            System.out.println("null "  + i + "  " + j);
        }
        else {
            if (aa[i][0].equals(String.valueOf(SAVEID))) {
                aaa[i][j]     = aa[i][1];
                aaa[i][j + 1] = aa[i][2];
                aaa[i][j + 2] = aa[i][3];
                aaa[i][j + 3] = aa[i][4];
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(aaa[0][0]);
System.out.println(aaa[0][1]);
System.out.println(aaa[0][2]);
System.out.println(aaa[0][3]);
```

Comment: Where does the `20` come from in the example you want to extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only 4 values are needed from the input array are needed, why not just read *these specific values*?

```java
String[] result = new String[4];

try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Turmas.txt")) // input closed automatically
    .useDelimiter(";|\\R")  // use character class \R to match line-feed characters 
) {
    if (input.hasNext()) {
        input.next(); // skip the 1st token

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length && input.hasNext(); i++) {
            result[i] = input.next();
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
        null, "An error occurred, try restarting the program!", 
        "ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
    );
}
```

---

If it is needed to read the *columns* with indexes `[1..4]` from the file containing 6 columns per line, it is cleaner to read the source file line by line, split each line by `;`, skip 1 column with index 0, and keep the 4 columns.

```java
String[][] result = new String[100][4];

try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Turmas.txt"))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length && input.hasNextLine(); i++) {
        String[] parts = input.nextLine().split(";");
        for (int j = 1; j < Math.min(result[i].length, parts.length); j++) {
            result[i][j - 1] = parts[j];
        }
    }    
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
        null, "An error occurred, try restarting the program!", 
        "ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
```

runs again with a value of j = 1 after it completes the first iteration, so when it gets to the expression `aaa[i][j+3]` the second index evaluates to **4**, which of course is illegal. I'm not sure why you used a **for** loop there, since you manually increment the index values as you assign the **aaa** values?